# remove class using child selector not working in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a very basic question. I want to remove one class using `removeClass()` attribute and using Child Selector. My [Fiddle Attempt](https://jsfiddle.net/unbreakable/nzyob6o6/1/)

```
<h2>Song</h2>

<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        Hello
    </div>
</div>


<div class="a">
    <div class="c">
        Hello
    </div>
</div>

<script> $(".a>.b").removeClass(".b");</script>
```

Comment: Remove .b from removeclass method. Use removeClass("b")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yu must not use . (dot) in removeClass();

```
<script> $(".a>.b").removeClass("b");</script>
```

Comment: feels silly now. had spent 15 min for this. anyways thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `.` from class name, in this case `.b` should be `b` inside `removeClass()`.

```js
$(".a >.b").removeClass("b");
```

```css
.a{
  border: 1px solid red!important;    
}
.b{
  border: 1px solid green!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Song</h2>

<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        Hello
    </div>
</div>


<div class="a">
    <div class="c">
        Hello
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: feel silly now. had spent 15 min for this. anyways thanks.

Comment: This kind of things happen. Don't worry.

Comment: Your answer got downvoted by some (not me, I upvoted) because you wrote first line as remove DOT in removeClass. I know you are telling the right stuff but as a beginner and by going through the answer quickly one would think that you want the DOT in "(DOT)removeClass" to be removed. just saying.

Comment: I updated the explanation. Hope it would help other people. Thanks for pointing out the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is correct, just that you don't have a class name `.b` but `b`

You should remove the `.(dot)` from removeClass

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $(".a>.b").removeClass("b");
});
```

Working Fiddle: **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nzyob6o6/4/)**

Comment: Thanks Bhai. feels silly now. had spent 15 min for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
You may also try this way,


    <style>
    .a {color:blue}
    .b {color:red}

    </style>
    <h2>Song</h2>

    <div class="a">
        <div class="b">
            Hello
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="c">
            Hello
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {   
       $(".a").find('.b').removeClass('b');
//or 
$(".a").children('.b').removeClass('b');
    });
    </script>
```